# Is declaring "belongs_to model_name" less secure than declaring "belongs_to model_id"? Are there any differences?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say my Tweet belongs to a User

Is it better (as in are there any security, ease of use or other reasons...) to declare:

```
attr_accessible :user
```

OR

```
attr_accessible :user_id
```

OR just both

```
attr_accessible :user, :user_id
```

Comment: I it has_many Tweets, it wouldn't have a tweet_id in it, just `tweets`

Comment: edited question to reflect what I actually wanted to ask

Answer (score 0):

If your `User` `has_many :tweets` your user wouldn't have a tweet_id or a tweet. It would have an array of tweets. `attr_accessible` whitelists attributes so that they can be mass assigned.

What exactly were you trying to do by defining the `attr_accessible :tweet`?

Instead of using attr_accessible for :tweet, or :user Rails provides

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :tweets`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I asked the wrong question for some reason...brain fart. Not trying to do anything just curious if there is any reason why I shouldn't declare attr_accesible :user